# Why does this ScrollViewer not produce horizontal scroll bars?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I've created the following page in WinRT / Metro, and expected to get both horizontal and vertical scrollbars from the ScrollViewer, as the content area is larger than the screen and ScrollViewer in both dimensions. Can anyone spot any error here?

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
x:Class="ScrollViewerTestPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">     

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="2500" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" Height="1200" Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>     
</Grid>
</Page>
```

The data is initialized in the constructor like this:

```
var model = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) model.Add("" + i);
DataContext = model;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a scrollview property for a horizontal scrollbar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility

Comment: Ouch.. just realized I'd forgot a slightly important negation in the question phrasing :) Question edited.